# Django test database is using local db.sqlite3, not running in memory

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-testing, django-database

When I run Django tests that inserts data into the database, it will insert to my local `db.sqlite3` and **preserve** it when the tests finishes. I don't want this to happen, and it shouldn't be [according to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database):

> Regardless of whether the tests pass or fail, the test databases are
>   destroyed when all the tests have been executed.

My unit test:

```py
from unittest import TestCase

from web.constants import USER_TYPE_CONTRACTOR
from web.models import User


class LoginTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.demo_user_1_username = 'c2'
        User.objects.create(username=self.demo_user_1_username, password='c12345678')

    def test_user_defaults_to_contractor(self):
        demo_user_1 = User.objects.get(username=self.demo_user_1_username)
        self.assertEqual(demo_user_1.user_type, USER_TYPE_CONTRACTOR)

    def doCleanups(self):
        """Delete demo data from database"""
        # I needed to do this as workaround
        # demo_user_1 = User.objects.get(username=self.demo_user_1_username)
        # demo_user_1.delete()
```

The user `c2` is now in the `db.sqlite3`, so when I run the test again, it fails as username `c2` already exists.

I've tried to do this in `settings.py`:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
}
DATABASES['default']['TEST'] = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test_db.sqlite3'),
}
```

But `test_db.sqlite3` is not created.

How can I use an in-memory sqlite3 db so it doesn't affect my local db when testing?

Comment: I do not know whether this is the cause of your problem but the docs you quote recommend using ```django.test.TestCase``` rather than ```unittest.TestCase``` when running tests with db access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here, how @Chris mentioned in direct usage of `TestCase` from `unitetest` module, the hierarchical chain looks like this:

```
TestCase->TransactionTestCase->SimpleTestCase->unittest.TestCase
```

How [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase) summaries:

> [TestCase] - This is the most common class to use for writing tests in Django. It
>   inherits from TransactionTestCase (and by extension SimpleTestCase).
>   **If your Django application doesn’t use a database, use SimpleTestCase.**

Here:

> When I run Django tests that inserts data into the database, it will
>   insert to my local db.sqlite3 and **preserve** it when the tests finishes.

**NOTE**: In your case, tests are using the actual database, which leads to a  data loss and population with mock data. **Never use such workflow!**

Actually, tests mustn't use your actual database at all, by default for `sqlite3` backend Django will handle in-memory database, destruction of the database can be controlled using the flag `--keepdb`. Generally speaking, the flow is as follows:

1. Test database will be created with the same credential as actual
   but the name will be `test_<actual_db_name>`. It is even possible to access the database between test execution in case if it is not deleted every time after tests have passed (`--keepdb`).
2. Before test execution, the test DB will be in a state as actual
   with `python manage.py migrate` executed, though you can omit migration execution via overriding `MIGRATION_MODULES` env variable.

So, the solution is to switch to the `django.test.TestCase` usage instead.

Comment: Thanks. Using `from django.test import TestCase` instead of `from unittest import TestCase` is working perfectly.